# Как узнать какой драйвер содержит источник ODBC?

Tags: sql, база-данных, odbc

SQL запросы для каждой базы разные. Источник данных ODBC содержит драйвер, который имеет функции, для работы с определённой базой данных. Т.е. можно писать один SQL код, и он будет работать в той БД драйвер которого содержит источник ODBC. Так вот как узнать для какой драйвер на данный момент используется? или когда мы подключаемся к БД ODBC сам выбирает нужный драйвер для работы с определённой БД?

Answer (score 1):

Панель настроек Windows - ODBC DataSource Administrator, связка ODBC с конкретным драйвером задается свойством *DataSource*